# External CSS affecting the <h1> of my JQuery Mobile header

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am using a plugin that has an external css and styles the h1 tags. However even thought I added divisions in my page, the external css is affecting the h1 of the header "Activity Page" in my  JQuery Mobile app.

Any suggestion?

```
<div data-role="header" id="header">
   <h1>Activity</h1>
 <a href="#panel" class="panel-toggle">Open left panel</a>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">

<div class="scroll" id="scroll">
    <ul class="list">
        <li>
            <h1>A</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>Aa</li>
                <li>Aa</li>
                <li>Aa</li>
                <li>Aa</li>
                <li>Aa</li>
            </ul> ......................
```

Image from my header

[image]

Comment: change css of the plugin.

Comment: Hey guys. I am new in web app development. Anyways I found the way to target using css by #scroll h1{...}. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `h1` tag css style in style tag. Like if you want to override font-style property the you can add

```
<style>
    h1 {
      font-style:normal;
    }
</style>
```

into your head `<head>` tag.

Comment: And if that still does not work try to add !important annotation after your style declaration like this: `font-style:normal !important;`